# remove files under specific folder

Tags: linux, files, find, rm

What is the diff between the following two approach ?

```
find /calc -type f -delete
find /calc -type f  -exec rm -f {} +
```

my target is to remove any jar file/s under calc folder

any prefered of one of the options?

Comment: I update the question so rm -f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) tag, there's no difference. The `-delete` option will turn on the `-depth` option, so files may get removed in a different *order* but the result will be the same. The `-delete` option will only remove one file at a time while the `-exec ... {} +` option will remove multiple files at a time, but still the same files will be removed.

Beyond that, `-delete` is not yet a POSIX-specified option, so for cross-platform compatibility you may prefer the `-exec` habit.